# Is there any way to authenticate user with okta for accessing content from S3 bucket through Cloudfront without any changes to Downstream applications

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, amazon-cloudfront, okta

Hope everyone is doing great!

I have a problem statement -
I want to access two S3 bucket content containing some files - /secured and /unsecured.

I have setup two S3 buckets and cloudfront distribution and route53 setup.

cloudfront is mapped with S3 buckets as origin. we need to authenticate one bucket files with okta and other bucket files should be available without authentication.

I have two downstream application where user is requesting for a file in current scenario and there is no authentication for now.

Ideal case scenario will be/ or the one I wanted to create is -

User makes a request to downstream application and that request should come and after that user should be authenticated first , if he/she is authenticated with okta oidc with token then route53 will get that file which will call cloudfront that will call secured S3 bucket.

Currently I dont/can't make any changes with downstream applications for any token or extra piece of code.
Anything I want to do is on backend/ api side

I have tried lambdaEdge but it have some limitations with size.
I am skeptical about Amazon Cognito.

Without any changes to downstream application, I want to authenticate user who are requesting file for whether to return secured and unsecured.

I have also made one SPA which is in angular as a landing page.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

You have many options

CloudFront has the ability to generate [signed URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-urls.html) and [signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-signed-cookies.html)

Edge computing with [Lambda@Edge in the CloudFront Viewer Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-at-the-edge.html). You can do for example simple authentication and authorization checks using JWTs.

If you have more complicated authentication and authorization logic, you can use  [S3 Object Lambda](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/olap-create.html). You configure your CloudFront origin to use an S3 Access Point that routes requests through a Lambda before allowing them into your S3 origin. This is typically used when you want to transform S3 objects, but can also be used for authorization and authentication.

A simple option that doesn't use CloudFront, if your users are interacting with your application through an API, is to have your API-generated [presigned URLs for S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html).